# Command not found: pdebuild fails, fakeroot succeeds

Tags: dpkg, chroot, pbuilder

I'm updating a debian package and I need to call an external build dependency which is actually a toolchain. It doesn't have a deb package so I can't provide `Build-Depends`. I've chosen to include it in the source archive instead, and am calling `ndk-build` which then calls various tools e.g. `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` which reside in a `toolchains` folder within the bundle.

When I reference this in `debian/rules: override_dh_auto_build-arch` I am using `$(CURDIR)` which resolves to `/build/pkgname-1.0`. It succeeds when running `fakeroot debian/rules build`, but not when I run the whole process using `pdebuild`. I get the following output when building for `i386`:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/build/pkgname-1.0'
NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/build/pkgname-1.0/android/ /build/pkgname-1.0/android-ndk-r12/ndk-build
make[2]: Entering directory '/build/pkgname-1.0'
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : dpfp <= dpfp.c
make[2]: /build/pkgname-1.0/android-ndk-r12/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
/build/pkgname-1.0/android-ndk-r12/build/core/build-binary.mk:472: recipe for target '/build/pkgname-1.0/android//obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/dpfp/__/__/examples/dpfp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/build/pkgname-1.0/android//obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/dpfp/__/__/examples/dpfp.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory '/build/pkgname-1.0'
```

Is this a `chroot` pathing issue? The files definitely exist in the folder shown as I have added `ls -R` when troubleshooting and I can see:

```
/build/pkgname-1.0/android-ndk-r12/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin:
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
```

I've tried adding the folder to `PATH`, calling `sh ndk-build`, explicitly moving the bundle folder to `$(CURDIR)` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: As you said source archive , have you tried building deb for particular tool that was troubling you and building again ?

Comment: Yes, but the source archive does not use android. The change that I am making is to add Android support.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if is typed right, or is just error from code of Stackexchange.

You typed 2 file and say are the same file.

`/build/pkgname-1.0/android-ndk-r12/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`

and

`/build/pkgname-1.0/android-ndk-r12/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin:arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`

One it have `/` after `.../bin` and another one it have `:`

Take a look also on rights of the file.

Comment: You're not reading the `ls -R` output correctly. The paths are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade `pbuilder` and `debootstrap` , according to [pbuilder User's Manual](http://pbuilder.alioth.debian.org/#pbuildercreatefail)

> It often happens that pbuilder cannot create the latest chroot. Try upgrading pbuilder and debootstrap. It is currently only possible to create software that handles the past. Future prediction is a feature which may be added later after we have become comfortable with the past.
>
> There are people who occasionally back port debootstrap to stable versions; hunt for them.
>
> When there are errors with the debootstrap phase, the debootstrap script needs to be fixed. pbuilder does not provide a way to work around debootstrap.

Comment: Debootstrap succeeds, I can see the chroot environment on disk. And chrooting into it succeeds as every prior build step is successfully executed, including running `./configure`. This is not a debootstrap issue.